# how to retain a button1 clicks action with a sleep against another button2 click action without sleep

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is I have two labels and two buttons in two different update panel in ASP.Net. The update panels contains two buttons. When buttons are clicked it will update the corresponding label text. The issue is, suppose I gave a delay of 5 seconds in my button1_click() method, when I click button1 and button2 immediately, label2 is gettin updated, whereas label1 is not getting updated.

Can you suggest where I'm going wrong?

```
protected void Button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Label1.Text = "Hello";
}

protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = "World";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Button Click Event, Update the Update Panel where the Second Label presents like below:

```
UpdatePanel2.Update();
```